# Displaying users and their home directory but NOT WITH awk

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, cut

I have seen similar questions and I actually found the solution using `awk` command, but I'm not allowed to use it in my homework.
so I want to know if there is another way of displaying all the users and their home directories in this form `user_name:user_home_directory` e.g : `root:/root` sorted by users.
this is the command that gave the desired output but I'm not allowed to use `awk` :

```
awk -F":" {'print $1":"$6'} /etc/passwd | sort
```

I think it has something to do with `grep` and/or `cut` because that is what I'm studying right know, but other command could be involved except for `sed` and `awk`

I'm using :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: With `cut`, you'll use the `-d` option to specify the field separator, and the `-f` option to supply the list of fields you want to keep. Check your cut man page.

Answer (score 1):

This site is not for solving your homework. However, I'll give you some hints:

- `man cut`. look at the -d and -f options
- `sed` can be used to remove the unwanted fields from a line. Such a field could match `:[^:]*:`
- in `bash` you can loop over the file with `read`; if you set `IFS=:`, you can split the field in different variables.